# JBoss 7.1. Please help configure "mail-session" via jboss-cli

Tags: jboss

I need to create smtp Mail connector via `jboss-cli` command line. So far I've managed to create `<mail-session>` node in configuration xml:

`/subsystem=mail/mail-session="java:/mail/myMail":add(jndi-name="java:/mail/myMail", from="noreply@acme.com")`

Default `standalone.xml` shows that `<smtp-server>` child node should be created beneath `<mail-session>` node, but I have no idea how to do it, JBoss Admin guide has no clues on the subject. If anyone can help with this I would really appreciate it.